# SELECT DISTINCT TWO COLUMNS and SUM another COLUMN's VALUES

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sum, distinct

Given two Tables that are Linked together

```
tbl_Gasoline 
--------------
ID | Type
-------------
1  | Diesel
2  | Kerosene
```

and

```
tbl_Expense
-----------------------------
ID | Price  | GasolineType (tbl_Gasoline foreign key)
-----------------------------
1  | 5000   | 1
2  | 4000   | 2
3  | 3000   | 1
```

I want to have an Output like this

```
tbl_GasolineExpense
----------------------------
ID |  Price  | Type
----------------------------
1  |  8000   | Diesel
2  |  4000   | Kerosene
```

I have tried to use a DISTINCT and SUM clauses but I can't seem to make a good query.
It's been long since I have used SQL so some help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
SELECT e.id, SUM(price) AS 'price', g.NAME 
FROM tbl_expense e
INNER JOIN tbl_gasoline g ON e.GasolineType = g.id 
GROUP BY e.id, g.NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please Try this.**

```
SELECT
e.id,
SUM(price) AS 'price',
g. NAME
FROM
    tbl_expense e
INNER JOIN tbl_gasoline g ON e.GasolineType = g.id
GROUP BY
    g.id,g. NAME
```

Comment: Thanks @S. M Mohiuddin, but I have encountered some error when using the code saying that e.id is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select 
  g.ID,
  E.SUM(PRICE) as price,
  e.GasolineType 
from 
  tbl_Gasoline  g,tbl_Expense e 
where 
  g.ID=e.GasolineType group by e.GasolineType
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tbl_Gasoline.ID,SUM(tbl_Expense.Price),tbl_Gasoline.Type 
from tbl_Expense inner join tbl_Gasoline on tbl_Expense.GasolineType = tbl_Gasoline.ID 
group by tbl_Gasoline.ID
```